# In excel, when I use the shortcut Alt+H+O+I to resize the column, it will also paste what I have copied. What shortcut am I hitting accidentally?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, ribbon

I often use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> when I want to autofit the column. Sometimes when I am going quickly, excel resizes the column and then pastes whatever is on the clipboard. Since I have the entire column selected when I do this, excel will sometimes crash from having to paste in an entire column of data, which is frustrating. I must be hitting another shortcut when I do this. Which one is it? (That way I can be careful not to hit it in the future.)

Comment: "pastes whatever is on my keyboard" do you mean "pastes whatever is **in my pasteboard**"?

Comment: What Excel version are you using?  Have you recorded any macros that have been assigned a Shortcut key?

Comment: I've successfully executed `Alt+H+O+I` in `2013` & `2016` both to resize the Column while selecting Cell & Entire Column also ,, Excel does't Paste the Copied/Cut value !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only you can say for sure!

My money's on <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

(ie. you're going too fast and missing the <kbd>O</kbd>)

...which, if you have a column selected, will insert a column with the data on your clipboard in it.

(tested on MS Excel 2007 12.0.4518.1014)

[image: sample image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the hotkey for Insert Cells. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is the Home tab, <kbd>I</kbd> pulls out the 'Insert' dropdown, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>E</kbd>) hits the first option, which is 'Insert Cells' or, if you have a column in your clipboard, 'Insert Copied Cells'.

Comment: what does `Alt-H-I-Enter` execute? On Office 2016 the first option is "Row Height" so it won't paste anything

Comment: Insert Cells. I edited in a screenshot and more detailed explanation. Remember that OP is starting the key sequence having already selected an entire column so I don't think you can get to a state where 'row height' is an option.

Comment: ah `Alt-H-I` vs `Alt-H-O-I`. I misread it, the shortcuts are the same on 2016

Comment: @AlexM, `Alt+H+I+Enter` never resizes the Column whether you select cell or entire Column. It's for `INSERT CEll/ROW/COLUMN`, I've tried in `2013 & 2016` also.

Comment: @RajeshS yes, but the OP is proposing that he's making a typo in his shortcut entry. He's asking for likely suggestions as to what he's hit instead of `Alt+H+O+I`. This COULD be it.

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is it. What is curious, is that I can undo my last action (getting rid of the pasted data) and the column will still be resized, so it seems as though I am hitting Alt-H-O-I and then Alt-H-I-Enter

Comment: That's.. hard to explain!